# Python condensed parameter

Tags: python, function

I've got an array I'm passing to an object

```
details = [
    ('my', 'month', 'current', 'percent', 'percent'),
    ('my', 'month', 'current', 'value', 'decimal'),
]
```

I'm passing it into a function

```
mappings = {
  '_'.join(detail): get_revenue_row_item(metric_data, *detail)
  for detail in details
}
```

The receiving function looks like this:

```
def get_revenue_row_item(data, *path):
```

I'm looking to separate the first 4 items in the `()`from the last one in the receiving function.

```
first_four_strings_of_path = ???
last_strings_of_path = ???
```

I'm very new to Python, can anyone help?

**My final goal is to pass the first 4 items as one parameter, and the last item as a second parameter.**

Comment: p = `('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')` is a tuple, you can just index `p[0:4]` and `p[4]`

Comment: or better a=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...n.....,9) and can be split to two by a[:-1] and a[-1]

Comment: What is `metric_data` ?

Comment: How can I change that array to have a tuple and along with a separate param? `details=[{property1: ('blah','blah'), property2: next_item}]` ?

Answer (score -1):

Lets say your

```
details = [
    ('my', 'month', 'current', 'percent', 'percent'),
    ('my', 'month', 'current', 'value', 'decimal'),
]
```

now using `a[:-1]` and `a[-1]`:

```
patched = [('_'.join(i[:-1]),i[-1]) for i in details]
```

gives:

```
[('my_month_current_percent', 'percent'), ('my_month_current_value', 'decimal')]
```